# Django: how to log exceptions from management commands?

Tags: python, django, exception, error-handling, command

I don't receive mails from errors happened in commands.

```
python deebate\manage.py test_logging_errors --settings=deebate.settings.local --traceback
```

the command:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    class Command(BaseCommand):
        help = "test unicode and logging"

        def handle(self, *args, **options):
            print(u"|`»|Ð".encode('ascii'))
```

Obviously this throws

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbb' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have `DEBUG = False`

LOGGING setting is

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
       # I always add this handler to facilitate separating loggings
        'debug_log_file':{
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(ROOT_PROJECT_INTERNAL, 'logs', 'debug.log'),
            'maxBytes': '16777216', # 16megabytes
            'backupCount': 10,
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'warning_log_file':{
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(ROOT_PROJECT_INTERNAL, 'logs', 'warning.log'),
            'maxBytes': '16777216', # 16megabytes
            'backupCount': 10,
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'django_log_file':{
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(ROOT_PROJECT_INTERNAL, 'logs', 'django.log'),
            'maxBytes': '16777216', # 16megabytes
            'backupCount': 10,
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },

    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins', 'django_log_file'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'core': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins', 'debug_log_file', 'warning_log_file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

and then i have Sentry too.

`debug.log` and `warning.log` are regularly filled by the app.

How do i catch that exception? Why Django doesn't catch that?

Comment: I don't believe that Django's default logging mechanism applies to management commands, unless you're calling them from inside a view, so you'll probably have to handle any exceptions yourself.

Comment: what is the best way to achieve it? a very big try catch? =)

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't bother catching it, if running from the command line. If there's a bug in an admin command, I'd want to know about it, so I can fix it.

Comment: ok i mean try except to log exception somewhere, not to suppress it

Comment: @Aya the use case is where a management command is being called automatically (eg from a cron) rather than manually. In this case, unless the exception is logged, you won't know about it, which could be a critical problem. Also, you can set up the logger to print the error to the console in addition to logfile/sentry/EmailAdmins, so you will know about it even if you run the command manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the [AdminEmailHandler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler) to get an email for error from management commands

Comment: i have that in my LOGGING setup, but i don't get the emails

Comment: have you tried explicitly setting up the AdminEmailHandler? You could use django logging handler AdminEmailHandler to achieve what you are looking for

Comment: sorry first time i didn't realize what you meant!

Comment: As far as I understand, this still requires you to explicitly log your error from the management command. I want the logger to log any (unexpected) exceptions coming from all commands.

Answer (score 14):

I appreciated [this article](https://mpcabd.xyz/make-django-management-commands-send-errors-email-admins/) which explains how to setup your `AdminEmailHandler`, but also to modify your `manage.py` to catch exceptions and log them, so that ALL management commands will send the email.